# Labels in an animation

Tags: python-3.x, animation, label

What is wrong with this moving label delta_label? How to edit the script to have a point that moves together with the label delta_label? The line should connect the point and the label. The label moves a little bit, but not much and wrong and is not flow. Thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

data = {
    'ra': [0, 2, -1, 3],
    'dec': [0, 1, 3, -2],
    'pmra_cor': [0.1, -0.1, 0, 0.1],
    'pmdec_cor': [0.1, 0, -0.1, -0.1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(df['ra'], df['dec'], s=20, color='blue')

factor = 1
num_frames = 100

# Create a text annotation for displaying elapsed time
time_label = ax.annotate(
    '',  
    xy=(0.1, 0.9),  
    xycoords='axes fraction',
    fontsize=12,  
    fontfamily='Trebuchet',
    color='black'
)

# Create a text annotation for the 'delta' label
delta_label = ax.annotate(
    'delta',  
    xy=(df['ra'][0], df['dec'][0]),  
    xytext=(20, 20),  
    textcoords='offset points',
    fontsize=12,  
    fontfamily='Trebuchet',
    color='red'
)

# Create a line to connect the 'delta' label and the point
line, = ax.plot([], [], color='black')

def update(frame):
    new_ra = df['ra'] + frame * factor * df['pmra_cor']
    new_dec = df['dec'] + frame * factor * df['pmdec_cor']
    sc.set_offsets(list(zip(new_ra, new_dec)))

    # Update the elapsed time label
    time_label.set_text('Elapsed time: {} years'.format(factor * frame))

    # Update the position of the 'delta' label
    delta_label.set_position((new_ra[0], new_dec[0]))

    # Update the line connecting the 'delta' label and the point
    line.set_data([new_ra[0], new_ra[0] + 0.5], [new_dec[0], new_dec[0] + 0.5])

    return sc, time_label, delta_label, line

# Create an animation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=num_frames, interval=200, blit=True)

plt.show()
```